# Getting T4-generated .resx files to build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t4, resx, msbuild-4.0

In our web application, I'm co-opting the `iu-Cans-CA` locale as a pseudo-locale where string resource keys are used as the values as well. This is to provide an aid for automation testing. To generate the `.resx` for this locale, I'm using a T4 template.

The `.resx` is generated correctly, but something's wrong: the resource file isn't being compiled into the assembly like the other *real* translations are. I finally figured out the cause. Because the T4 template is used to generate the `.resx`, the `.csproj` contains this:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Strings.iu-Cans-CA.resx">
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <DependentUpon>Strings.iu-Cans-CA.tt</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

For some reason, this is preventing the `.resx` from compiling. If I update the `.csproj` to this, it *does* compile:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Strings.iu-Cans-CA.resx">
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

I was hoping this would be the end of it, but now whenever the `.csproj` is loaded in Visual Studio, the project file is once again updated to the former structure, breaking the compilation of the resource file again.

Is there a way to fix things so that the generated/dependent `.resx` properly compiles as an embedded resource? Or is there a way to permanently break the dependency relationship so it doesn't keep getting restored? I realize I can rewrite the `.tt` so it generates a file with a different name, but I'd prefer finding a solution that doesn't require this since that is an atypical usage of T4 and I want to avoid too many WTFs.

Comment: Bah, closed as "Won't Fix" on the Connect site. Sometimes I wonder why I bother filing bugs into that black hole: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/801997/t4-generated-resx-files-not-compiling

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is to strip the DependentUpon metadata from the T4 generated EmbeddedResource elements before the build really kicks off. The following modification of the BeforeBuild target in my project file works for me:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <!-- Fix MSBuild issue where T4 generated .RESX files do not get compiled properly into satellite assemblies -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <GeneratedEmbeddedResource Include="@(EmbeddedResource)" Condition="'%(EmbeddedResource.DependentUpon)' != ''">
      <DependentUpon></DependentUpon>
    </GeneratedEmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="@(EmbeddedResource)" Condition="'%(EmbeddedResource.DependentUpon)' != ''"/>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="@(GeneratedEmbeddedResource)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an output path for the .resx file.

If you leave `Output.Project` empty and don't specify a directory/path in `Output.File`, the generated file will be *DependentUpon* the .tt file itself.

Comment: Where is `Output.Project` and `Output.File` specified? Could you post some code? I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: You need T4 Toolbox. See [here](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/03/t4-toolbox-generating-files-in-different-folders-and-projects/). I assumed you were using it because you mentioned templates.